# Access VBA Code not setting a variable to queried value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am kinda new to VBA, been working with it for 2 months but I'm stuck now. I have an access code that I use to calculate total hours for a project from a table with records of hours. My code successfully calculates hours for 3 categories but not the last two. I pull values from a query that sums up hours by project and save it to a variable, then update my project records with the correct values.

Update: for the 4th check I used select to see if it would work better that way instead of using an IF statement, it was originally an if statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

my code is as follows:

```
Dim First As Integer
Dim Second As Integer
Dim Third As Integer
Dim Fourth As Integer
Dim Fifth As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryHermosaPCHoursSum1st", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs.FindNext "PlanCheck Like " _
    & Chr(34) & "*" & Me.PlanCheck & "*" & Chr(34)

    If rs.NoMatch Then
            First = 0
        Else
            First = (rs![SumOfHours])
    End If

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryHermosaPCHoursSum2nd", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs.FindNext "PlanCheck Like " _
    & Chr(34) & "*" & Me.PlanCheck & "*" & Chr(34)

    If rs.NoMatch Then
            Second = 0
        Else
            Second = (rs![SumOfHours])
    End If

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryHermosaPCHoursSum3rd", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs.FindNext "PlanCheck Like " _
    & Chr(34) & "*" & Me.PlanCheck & "*" & Chr(34)

    If rs.NoMatch Then
            Third = 0
        Else
            Third = (rs![SumOfHours])
    End If
```

Up to here it works fine.

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryHermosaPCHoursSum4th", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs.FindNext "PlanCheck Like " _
    & Chr(34) & "*" & Me.PlanCheck & "*" & Chr(34)

    Select Case True
        Case rs.NoMatch
            Fourth = 0
        Case Else
            Fourth = (rs![SumOfHours])
    End Select
```

When I run the code line by line it seems to correctly grab the value of rs![SumOfHours] but fails to pass the value to Fourth and Fifth. I have a test record that has 15 matching hours that the query correctly sums but the code leaves it as zero.

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryHermosaPCHoursSum5th", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs.FindNext "PlanCheck Like " _
    & Chr(34) & "*" & Me.PlanCheck & "*" & Chr(34)

    If rs.NoMatch Then
            Fifth = 0
        Else
            Fifth = (rs![SumOfHours])
    End If

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblHermosaBeachPC", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs.FindNext "ID Like " _
    & Chr(34) & "*" & Me.PlanCheck & "*" & Chr(34)
    rs.Edit
        rs![1stSetHours] = First
        rs![2ndSetHours] = Second
        rs![3rdSetHours] = Third
        rs![4thSetHours] = Fourth
        rs![5thSetHours] = Fifth
    rs.Update
```

Comment: Not a solution but a remark. You're using repetitive code, calculating per category. This should be a red flag that your approach is wrong. Consider having 150 categories..... One simple query should suffice.

Comment: Why are you saving aggregate data and not just calculating when needed? Why did you change the code for Fourth to use Select Case? Should be `Select Case rs.NoMatch` then `Case True`

Comment: in Fourth, use an IF as you did in the other ones. Something like `If rs.NoMatch Then Fourth = 0 Else Fourth = (rs![SumOfHours])`

Comment: And just a suggestion. Why using so many Recordsets? IF you are just looking a value in a specific record, maybe Dlookup will help you.

Comment: The reason I use the different record sets is that I need it to add up multiple hours for the same project. I have a project table and a hours table, each project has multiple entries for hours in the hours table and I want the sum of those hours to be transferred to the projects table.

Comment: @Rene Would I be able to have it sum the data in each category per project

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I originally had all the same, Using the IF rs.NoMatch but it was not working for the 4th and 5th case. It doesnt seem to work with either Select Case or IF.

Comment: @Luis, yes, you should be able to create a query that sums the hours per project.

Comment: As already commented, the Select Case syntax is wrong, however, if the IF is not working then there is something else causing issue and we cannot debug 'something else'. Also already noted, a single query should serve or use domain aggregate function calls for each field.

Comment: Correction about the Select Case, syntax is correct, logic is wrong.

Comment: @June7 So I figured out that the 'something else' issue is that rs.NoMatch is being set as True even though it succesfully finds a record. Any idea what would cause a false NoMatch?

Comment: None. Eliminate the Find method. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving aggregate data is usually unnecessary and poor design. Calculate aggregate data when needed.

A single query should be able to calculate all 5 aggregate values then a single recordset can retrieve fields. Why use wildcard instead of =?

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qryHermosaPCHoursSum WHERE PlanCheck = '" & Me.PlanCheck & "'", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Set rsDest = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblHermosaBeachPC WHERE PlanCheck = '" & Me.PlanCheck & "'", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rsDest.Edit
        rsDest![1stSetHours] = rs!First
        rsDest![2ndSetHours] = rs!Second
        rsDest![3rdSetHours] = rs!Third
        rsDest![4thSetHours] = rs!Fourth
        rsDest![5thSetHours] = rs!Fifth
    rsDest.Update
End If
```

Or instead of the rsDest recordset object:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblHermosaBeachPC SET 1stSetHours=" & rs!First & _ 
", 2ndSetHours=" & rs!Second & ", 3rdSetHours=" & rs!Third & _ 
", 4thSetHours=" & rs!Fourth & ", 5thSetHours=" & rs!Fifth & _ 
" WHERE PlanCheck = '" & Me.PlanCheck & "'"
```